# Pear Mail not sending HTML mime

Tags: php, pear, command-line-interface

I am using the command line (shell_exec) to run a PHP script that sends multiple emails with PEAR Mail. (I need to run it in the background, otherwise the server crashes.)

When I test it on my localhost it sends the HTML content perfectly, but when I run it on the live/remote web server it only sends the text content, not the HTML content. When I run the scripts (albeit only one email at a time) they send with HTML content.

Is there any reason why the command line version only sends text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was accessing my HTML email template via HTTP. I just swapped it out for a local path and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check that all of the required packages are installed on the live/remote server.

You should also check that the include_path is set up the same - e.g. compare the include_pat lines in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini against /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: I have several other scripts on my site that use PEAR mail, and they send the HTML perfectly. It is just when I use the command line that it sends only text content, no HTML. I am using a hosting provider and they assured me that all the packages were installed. Just to be clear, the content that I specify in `$mime->setTXTBody($text)` is coming through, but not whatever I specify in `$mime->setHTMLBody($html)`.